# Pegar valores com nomes no JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Tenho esse seguinte `JSON`:

```
{"nome_rede":"lucasl","nome":"Lucas Lima","imagem":"http:\/\/intranet.supersoft.com.br\/novo\/usuarios\/fotos\/lucasl.jpg"}
```

Como faço para pegar ele usando AJAX?

Até agora meu código está assim, não esta pegando nada.

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/novo/engine/listarUsersGosteiPublicacaoFixa.php?id_publicacao="+$('#id_publicacao').val()+"", 
                success: function(data) {

                        for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                            var imagem = data[i].imagem;
                            var nome = data[i].nome;
                            var nome_rede = data[i].nome_rede;

                        }

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está tentando acessar de forma errada, para acessar os dados desse JSON você deve fazer dessa maneira:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "/novo/engine/listarUsersGosteiPublicacaoFixa.php?id_publicacao=" + $('#id_publicacao').val() + "",
  success: function(data) {

    var imagem = data["imagem"];
    var nome = data["nome"];
    var nome_rede = data["nome_rede"];

  }
});
```

Caso o JSON esteja retornando um array de objetos como nesse exemplo:
`[{"nome_rede":"lucasl","nome":"Lucas Lima","imagem":"img"}]'`

a solução seria essa:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "/novo/engine/listarUsersGosteiPublicacaoFixa.php?id_publicacao=" + $('#id_publicacao').val() + "",
  success: function(data) {

    for (var i in data) { //vai passar por todos os objetos dentro do array
      imagem = data[i]["imagem"];
      nome = data[i]["nome"];
      nome_rede = data[i]["nome_rede"];
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: mas se tiver mais de uma informação? por exemplo, dois nomes, duas imagens, dois nome_rede, tem que ser no loop certo?

Comment: Um minuto ja ajusto pra vc

Comment: Nesse caso ai data não seria um objeto, seria um array

Answer (score 0):

Tentei fazer conforme o Antony Alkmim informou, porém não consegui, o que funcionou pra mim foi:

```
//Obtem o objeto httpRequest para fazer requisições AJAX, de acordo com o browser
function getHttpRequest(){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // Outros browsers
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        // Internet Explorer
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return req;
}

// Busca endereço baseado no CEP
function preencheEndereco(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var req = getHttpRequest();
    var cep = document.querySelector("input[name='CEPEndereco']");
    var url = "https://viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep.value + "/json/";
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if (req.status == 200) {
                // Converte o retorno em JSON para um objeto válido
                var retorno = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                LogradouroEndereco.value = retorno.logradouro;
                BairroEndereco.value =retorno.bairro;
                UFEndereco.value = retorno.uf;
                CidadeEndereco.value = retorno.localidade;
                IDCidadeEndereco.value = retorno.ibge;              
            }
        }
    }
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send(null); 
}
```